# GetWriterForMessage() not called in Monotouch - is there a workaround?

Tags: web-services, soap, mono, xamarin.ios, asmx

I have ported over some code from a Windows application to Monotouch.
It is using ASMX Web Services to talk to some API.
The code fails on Monotouch 5 because the method

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.GetWriterForMessage()
```

is never called.

I have seen that in [Mono you will even get a `NotImplementedExeption`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572681/customizing-soap-headers-in-c-sharp-mono) but not in Monotouch. It simply gets ignored.

I need to find a way around this. I have to add custom headers to make the solution work. 
Any workarounds or maybe is there even a chance that this will be fixed soon?
(I also filed a bug report, but I'm asking here because I am desperately looking for a workaround).

**EDIT:**
I found kind of a workaround but it is very annoying to use.
In the auto generated reference file you will have to decorate each and every method with

```
[SoapHeader( "SessionKeyHeader", Direction = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderDirection.InOut )]
```

Then implement the custom soap header class but skip the GetXmlWriter() method.

Comment: Sarcastic? As an MS MVP I guess you know that I'm referring to classic ASP.NET web services, as introduced with .NET 2.0 (if I remember correctly)? What's the correct technical term?

Comment: I have never heard ASMX web services referred to as "web services 2.0". You could easily have been referring to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug has been filed at Xamarin about this issue.